# Laravel call to undefined method App\Seo::mapInto()

Tags: php, laravel

When I try to get my product SEO data with resource it returns

```
Call to undefined method App\Seo::mapInto()
```

## Code

`seo model`

```
public function seoable()
{
  return $this->morphTo();
}
```

`product model`

```
public function seo()
{
  return $this->morphOne(Seo::class, 'seoable');
}
```

`product resource`

```
'seo' => SeoResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('seo')),
```

My best guess is the `collection` in `SeoResource` causing this error, but not sure if it is what should i change it to?

**any idea?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you use `SeoResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('seo'))` but you have just one element and not a collection.

Hence, you can replace it with `new SeoResource($this->whenLoaded('seo'))` like this:

**Replace:**

```
'seo' => SeoResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('seo')),
```

**with:**

```
'seo' => new SeoResource($this->whenLoaded('seo')),
```

Comment: `Call to undefined function App\Http\Resources\SeoResource()`

Comment: i think you should try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/62852661/308578 use ::make() instead of ::collection()