# Laravel Call to undefined method App\\ Model ::mapInto(), vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Support\\Traits\\ForwardsCalls.php

Tags: php, laravel, collections, model, laravel-7

I'm trying to

```
public function show(Product $product)
{
    return ProductDetailResource::collection($product);
}
```

> Call to undefined method App\ Model ::mapInto(), exception:
> BadMethodCallException file
> vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\ForwardsCalls.php

then google and cant find any results

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just need to replace

```
public function show(Product $product)
{
    return ProductDetailResource::make($product);
}
```

instead of:

```
public function show(Product $product)
{
    return ProductDetailResource::collection($product);
}
```

because collection for $products and collection of product.

but we have one item here